# Trying to draw image in css

Tags: android, css, image, mobile, mobile-browser

i'm trying to so save network requests,thats why i want to implement close button of my mobile page in CSS. 
I used img2css website to generate the css, here is my solution: 
But it looks pretty bad in old mobile devices :
  [Here is a screenshot from Android 4.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czbEc.jpg)
At the left side is my css solution at the right side the original image. So as you see the css is a bit ugly.
Any suggestions how to draw this simple close button in CSS?

Comment: you can use `SVG` images

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this an awful lot, and learn some basic css:

```css
span.close
{
  display:block;
  width:32px;
  height:32px;
  color:#666;
  border:1px solid #666;
  border-radius:50%;
  font-size:28px;
  line-height:1;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
 <span class="close">&times;</span>
```

Comment: Tnx, your solution helped me!